# What does this cat/tr/perl command pipeline do?

Tags: perl

I'm not familiar with Perl. I want to know what is the effect of running this:

```
 cat file_name | tr -d '\000' | perl -pi -e 's/[^\n\040-\176]/#/g' >  new_file.out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read file with name "file_name", delete all symbols `\000` (Null symbol), 
replace all symbols that are not `\n` or between `\040-\0176` to `#`, and finally 
write result to "new_file.out"

Comment: ... Uselessly, since all of this could easily be done by Perl alone.

Comment: "Useless" is a bit overstated.  Let's say it makes more steps than it needs to.

Answer (score 3):

This does two things:

1. Strip any nulls from the file
2. Replace any unprintable characters with a '#' character.

Answer (score 2):

The perl `-pi` concerns me because `-i` means "Modify the input file in-place" and there's no input file there.

I believe that the entire command line could be shortened by removing `cat` and `tr and just using

```
perl -pe 's/[^\n\040-\176]/#/g' file_name >  new_file.out
```

And then you can actually take advantage of the `-i` switch and just use

```
perl -p -i -e's/[^\n\040-\176]/#/g' file_name
```

and the cleaned-up version will get put in the file `file_name`.

If you want a backup version for safety, change `-i` to `-i.bak` and it will put the new contents in `file_name` and keep the old in `file_name.bak`.

**Note**: My version is not exactly equivalent.  See comments below.

Comment: Indeed. There seems to be little point in removing nul characters and replacing all other control characters with a hash

Comment: That's a good catch.  My version is *not* identical to the original.  In the original, NULs would get removed, but in my version, they'd be replaced by `#`.